# Trim a returned value from a Kafka topic using python

Tags: python, regex, split, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple python module as follows:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'myTestTopic',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True)

for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    print(message)
```

This will return something like follows:

> b'&name=bob&gender=M&type=student&sId=1204&note=temp&'
>
> b'&name=bob&gender=M&type=student&sId=1204&'

My question is: Is there a neat way to remove/trim the first two characters e.g: (**b'**) and the last character (**'**) from each line that will be returned?

So essentially it will appear like:

> &name=bob&gender=M&type=student&sId=1204&note=temp&
>
> &name=bob&gender=M&type=student&sId=1204&

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the type of your response is [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) not string. You need to decode it, something like this should work:

```
message = str(message.value, encoding='utf-8')
print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
message.value.decode('utf-8')
```